# Unrecognized hash algorithm after upgrade to PHP 7.4

Tags: php, hash, php-7.4

I have just installed the php 7.4 and try to access at my account but I have an error.
Any Idea ?

```
Notice: Core\Hash::needsRehash() Algorithm "" not supported.
```

I also tried with not work

```
$algo = 'bcrypt';
$algo = 'argon2id';
```

The function

```
public static function needsRehash($hash, $algo = null)
{
  if (!isset($algo) || $algo == 'default') {
    $algo = PASSWORD_DEFAULT;
  } elseif ($algo == 'bcrypt') {
    $algo = PASSWORD_BCRYPT;
  } elseif ($algo == 'argon2id') {
    $algo = PASSWORD_ARGON2ID;
  }

  if (!is_int($algo)) {
    trigger_error('Core\Hash::needsRehash() Algorithm "' . $algo . '" not supported.');
  }
```

Comment: Your own error message tells, that the ``$algo`` is empty (``null``, ``false`` or an empty String). Maybe you can use ``var_dump(func_get_args())`` or ``debug_print_backtrace()`` in your functuon to get more information.

Answer (score 4):

You are checking if `$algo` is an integer, but in PHP 7.4 these constants are no longer integers; they are nullable strings.

From [PHP 7.4 Backward Incompatible Changes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration74.incompatible.php)

> Password hashing algorithm identifiers are now nullable strings rather
>   than integers.
>
> - PASSWORD_DEFAULT was int 1; now is NULL
> - PASSWORD_BCRYPT was int 1; now
>     is string '2y'
> - PASSWORD_ARGON2I was int 2; now is string 'argon2i'
> - PASSWORD_ARGON2ID was int 3; now is string 'argon2id'
>
> Applications
>   correctly using the constants PASSWORD_DEFAULT, PASSWORD_BCRYPT,
>   PASSWORD_ARGON2I, and PASSWORD_ARGON2ID will continue to function
>   correctly.

Your code is not using them correctly. You assume that they are integers and you explicitly check their value, but in reality you don't need to. In PHP7.4 you can use [`password_algos()`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/password_registry) to check whether the algorithm is present in your PHP installation. In previous PHP versions you can check with `defined(PASSWORD_ARGON2I)` whether the algorithm is defined.

For backwards compatibility the old integer values are also accepted, but should not be used. Just stick to the constants.

Answer (score 3):

You check for `!isset($algo)`, which means that if you pass in an empty string, the validation will fail. In this case, I believe that using `!isset()` is not appropriate, as its always set (except when its null - but you can test for that explicitly instead).

You can check for  `empty($algo)`, or if the parameter is equal to null. Checking for `empty()` will check for more than just empty strings and null-values (see below).

```
if (empty($algo) || $algo == 'default') {
// or
if ($algo === null || $algo == 'default') {
```

`isset()`:

> Determine if a variable is considered set, this means if a variable is declared and is different than NULL.

`empty()`:

> Determine whether a variable is considered to be empty. A variable is considered empty if it does not exist or if its value equals FALSE. empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist.

Comment: That is not what the question was asking about.